# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured for MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.15, JDK 17

Added Spring Data JPA, mongo-db dependency in pom.xml for database communication

Error Logs I saw some solves, but I dont have an application.yml file to change the 'url'

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.15)

2023-08-25 09:00:35.880  INFO 10812 --- [           main] c.lcwd.rating.RatingServiceApplication   : Starting RatingServiceApplication using Java 17.0.8 on pushpendra-ThinkPad-T460 with PID 10812 (/home/pushpendra/Documents/Workspace/Intellij/Microservice/RatingService/target/classes started by pushpendra in /home/pushpendra/Documents/Workspace/Intellij/Microservice/UserService)
2023-08-25 09:00:35.886  INFO 10812 --- [           main] c.lcwd.rating.RatingServiceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-25 09:00:37.529  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-08-25 09:00:37.532  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-25 09:00:37.559  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-25 09:00:37.644  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-08-25 09:00:37.644  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-25 09:00:37.646  INFO 10812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2023-08-25 09:00:38.671  INFO 10812 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2023-08-25 09:00:38.687  INFO 10812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-25 09:00:38.688  INFO 10812 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.79]
2023-08-25 09:00:38.841  INFO 10812 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-25 09:00:38.842  INFO 10812 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2835 ms
2023-08-25 09:00:38.964  WARN 10812 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-08-25 09:00:38.974  INFO 10812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-08-25 09:00:38.997  INFO 10812 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-25 09:00:39.020 ERROR 10812 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
This is my pom.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.15</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lcwd.rating</groupId>
    <artifactId>RatingService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RatingService</name>
    <description>This is Rating Service</description>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <excludes>
                   <exclude>
                      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                   </exclude>
                </excludes>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://userAdmin:admin@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT
      database: microservices

server:
  port: 8083
```

```
package com.lcwd.rating;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RatingServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(RatingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Till now only database configuration added in project, but when I run project I get error as mention in title.

Also try with uri as show below

```
mongodb://userAdmin:admin@localhost:27017
```

Also try with application.properties instead of application.yml

Double check the username, password, host, port no and database is also present.

Restart Intellij and run again.

Checkout stackoverflow questions, search on the Google, refer article, try with chatGPT also.

Comment: You can try to exclude automatic database injection`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })`

Comment: Try this also but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:** While using mongdb database you don't require **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** dependency because JPA (Java Persistence API) is a specification for managing relational databases and MongoDB is a NoSQL database. MongoDB uses a different data model and query language compared to traditional relational databases.

**Solution:** Just remove the below dependency from pom.xml and it will work fine.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```